# Magento 2 : How to Save Quote Data after order placed

Tags: magento2

**1. Observer Class**

```
<?php
namespace Simple\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Quote implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_objectManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        //Quote
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        // $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_data','custom_field');;
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
    }

}
```

**2. events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="sales_order_save_after">
         <observer name="save_data" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddCustomFieldValue"  />    
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your XML file  tag is missing.so correct with the following code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="sales_order_save_after">
         <observer name="save_data" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddCustomFieldValue"  />  
       </event>
     </config>
```

2. Correct Your Observer with following code.

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
class AddCustomFieldValue implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    )
    {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Fetch Quote Factory and add field to this function
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote) {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things,missing on your code.

***First, have tried to use quoteFactory but your do not inject  Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory at constructor***

***Your observer class name is wrong***,define observer class

`Vendor\Module\Observer\AddCustomFieldValue` at `events.xml` .But your observer class  name is  Quote .So Observer class name should be `AddCustomFieldValue`

**Observer Class:**

```
<?php

namespace Simple\Module\Observer;


class AddCustomFieldValue implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory     
    ) {

        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote =  $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
        if($quote){
            // do what ever you need
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Sir how i get quote data by 'reserved_order_id_'.. please take a look at my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279908/getting-null-on-quote-collection-by-reserved-order-id