# Getting Null on Quote Collection by Reserved Order Id

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3

I am trying to get quote data By

> reserved_order_id

I tried this code

```
protected $_quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->_quoteFactory           = $quoteFactory;

}
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
         $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('reserved_order_id', $orderId);
         $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 12);
        $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('base_subtotal_with_discount', 20.0000);
}
```

the first filter is returning **null** while `entity_id` and `base_subtotal_with_discount` is returning me the correct result

I tried all of them separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check this below collection and make sure that your reserved order should be unique.

If your if condition will be true then, records available othervise, records not available :

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
){
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;    
}
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->->addFieldToFilter('reserved_order_id', 'Your Order id')->getFirstItem();
    if($quote->getId())
    {
        // quote id found   
    } else {
        // quote id not found
    }
}
```

Hope, It will be helpful for you.

Comment: i checked my database there was a quote with reserved_order_id 0000082 i excuted following code having order_id = 82 i am still getting null

Comment: thank you its working fine now